# How can I achieve this effect where photos have a "bluish" theme with highly dramatic colors?

Tags: post-processing, reverse-engineering, effect, color-blue, tone-curves

Just wanted to see how this effect can be achieve in the images in [this Facebook set](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.669696223175835.1073741882.152133838265412&type=1).

If you notice closely there is a 'bluish' theme in the pics yet colours are standing out and there is more drama in the pics.

I understand this is definitely something to do with post processing and perhaps something to do with curve. 
I have client who has requested similar colour tone in pics and I have no idea how to do these properly. No matter what I try, I am not getting similar results.

Comment: Have you approached the photographer?

Comment: Note that you will probably get better answers if you can describe the effect in even more detail, and, best of all, post examples of things you've tried.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://youtu.be/GFuenozbiE0) may be of interest

Answer (score 0):

This look is a result of reducing the contrast of the blue channel, making the shadows bluer and the highlights less blue. You can do this with any curves or levels adjustment tool that lets you work on a single channel. Start by raising the low end until you get the amount of blue in the shadows that you want. Depending on how warm the lighting in the picture is to begin with, you may also want to lower the top end a small amount. The colors are also very saturated in general, so if you're not already starting out with photos like that, you might want to increase the saturation, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Photoshop you can get results like this with "Selective Color" tool.

- open up your image
- go to layers window (F7)
- click add adjustment layer in bottom menu of layers window
- select **Selective Color** and go to the **Properties** Tab (should be open by default)
- choose **Blacks** in **Colors** drop down menu
- move **Yellows** down to -10 (or below) and **Black** up to +10

Selective Color tool explained in detail: https://youtu.be/gaSshSGTacc?t=3m46s

Answer (score -2):

My guess is that this shading is a result of adjusting the color temperature when processing RAW files. If you don't have RAW files to work with, but you have Photoshop or similar, you could create a layer and fill it with a shade of blue and then use the multiply blend mode while adjusting opacity for a similar effect.

Comment: Color temperature adjustment applies to all brightness values in the image, and won't produce this "blue shadow" effect, unless you're starting out with very, very yellow lighting.